# Visual Studio 2022 .esproj start only

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js

Since Visual Studio 2022 17.7, esproj seems to be the new way to manage our vuejs project (njsproj).

However, I haven't found the correct parameters of launch.json to start only the vuejs app without opening a page in the browser.

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help